# I get CORS error when I try to access metadata stored on IPFS

Tags: axios, cors, blockchain, ethereum, ipfs

I am trying to fetch the metadata I stored on NFT.storage using axios, but each time I get this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'ipfs://bafyreib6hf354pwtnwxdmfllegogffvkv2dzsrgbithvjbzzewu757bxay/metadata.json' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

I have solved this issue many times when I used to do web2 development but don't know how to do this here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly access `ipfs://` prefixed content from a normal browser or js. Instead, you'd have to access it through a [gateway](https://docs.ipfs.io/concepts/ipfs-gateway).

Some popular gateways are ipfs.io, pinata, moralis..

This is an example usage of an ipfs gateway:
https://ipfs.io/ipfs/bafyreib6hf354pwtnwxdmfllegogffvkv2dzsrgbithvjbzzewu757bxay/metadata.json

Try making your axios request to this url